# Stack level too Deep - Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I've seen tons of these questions, but none of their solutions are working for me. I have a single test like so:

```
describe RolesController do
  describe "#delet" do 

    context "When the user is logged in" do 
      let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
      let(:admin) {FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
      let(:adminRole) {FactoryGirl.create(:adminRole)}

      it "Should allow admins to delete roles" do 
        sign_in admin
        put :destroy, :id => adminRole.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Simple, simple, simple. Yet I get the typical error:

```
  1) RolesController#delet When the user is logged in Should allow admins to delete roles
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
     # /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23
```

and I'm all like ... what? Again I have read dozens of questions on this and it seems to be something with factory girl but I cannot see what the issue here would be. I have tons of other tests that instantiate factory girl based object like this with no issue.

Comment: What does your stacktrace look like? In any event, you'll need to share your factories in order to get more specific help than is in the related questions.

Comment: be careful with `let` - it is lazy. When your test runs `sign_in admin`, it will instantiate the `admin` before running the test, but not the `user` or `adminRole`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related with Rspec. I got that same error in the same line of ActiveSupport instrumenter just running a script in production mode, with the Rspec excluded on that environment. I'm also running Ruby 2.0.0-p247 and Rails 4.

Comment: The error indicates that you've probably triggered an infinite loop.  It may have to do with a cyclical  dependency between your factories. Could you post the factory definitions?

Comment: Can you post the code called by `sign_in admin` along with the factory code for `admin` and `adminRole` please?

Comment: This is not what you asked for but you should rename adminRole to admin_role. Rubyists uses snake_case for variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do not use the variable you are defining with `let` inside the following code block as it triggers an endless recursion.

Answer (score -1):

I think some naming conflicts causing this stack level too deep error.

```
let(:adminRole) { FactoryGirl.create(:adminRole) }
```

How about you rename the `adminRole` factory to `:admin_role`:

```
factory :admin_role do
  ...
end
```

And change the `let` to follow [variable convention](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars):

```
let(:admin_role) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_role) }
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Downvoting because mentioning naming conventions is not helpful in solving the problem.